# Property 'start' does not exist on type 'ApolloServer'

Tags: visual-studio-code, apollo-server, tsconfig

I'm probably missing an obvious setting or something, but for some reason VS Code doesn't see `ApolloServer.start`, and I get an inline error:

```
Property 'start' does not exist on type 'ApolloServer'.
```

Can anyone see what I'm missing? It works by calling the usual `listen` method on the server, but I'm trying to add middleware, and this is the documented flow at [apollo's official docs](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server/tree/main/packages/apollo-server-express).

**tsconfig**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "types": ["node"],
        "esModuleInterop": true,
    },
    "include": [
        "apollo-server/*"
    ],
    "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

**index.ts**

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

import express from 'express'
import { ApolloServer, gql } from 'apollo-server-express'
import { readFileSync } from 'fs'
import { resolvers } from './resolvers'

const typeDefs = gql`readFileSync('./schema.graphql').toString('utf-8')`

async function startServer() {
    const server = new ApolloServer({
        typeDefs,
        resolvers,
    })
    
    await server.start() // <---- VSCode complains here
    const app = express()
    server.applyMiddleware({ app })
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE**

This question was regarding Apollo Server 2.0. The links have since been changed and Apollo is now on in version 3.0. If you're not dependent on version 2, I suggest updating your dependency to v3. For those of you stuck on this, here's the pattern:

```
// The ApolloServer constructor requires two parameters: your schema
// definition and your set of resolvers.
const server = new ApolloServer({ typeDefs, resolvers });

// The `listen` method launches a web server.
server.listen().then(({ url }) => {
  console.log(`  Server ready at ${url}`);
});
```

[Here's a fresh URL to confirm it in the docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/getting-started/)

FWIW, I found it right after I posted the question. This is a deprecated pattern. (Stale link removed)

Comment: The link doesn't work anymore

Comment: @JonathanBareket - Updated with a fresh link and code.